# Restore Windows 10 system image on new SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, system-restore

I need to switch to a new harddrive - HDD to SSD. 
I already created a system image of Windows 10 on an external harddrive.
How do I restore the system image on the new SSD, do I need to install Windows 10 on that SSD first?

Comment: I have the same problem: did you find a solution? If yes, please please share it. Thanks!

Comment: will be great if you mark the answer if you already solve it, I also wonder the way to switch it.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a system image via the GUI is not en efficient way to image Windows partition images, as it's easier and more efficient to create a WIM of the system via **[`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)**, versus a GUI created system image.  I go into this below, but to address your question:

1. Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Advanced Startup - Restart now

   - Troubleshoot > Advanced options > System Image Recovery
2. This can also be accessed through WinRE without booting to Windows:

   - Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while selecting Restart from the power options button on the logon screen
   - Force PC poweroff 2x consecutively once the Windows Bootloader begins to boot Windows

---

### Imaging

- One of the differences between the CLI method versus GUI is the system partition can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE, while all other partitions are able to be imaged while booted to Windows.

  - WIMs *(**W**indows **IM**age)* can be captured of an entire partition or individual folders/files and is the best method to use *(specify exclusions/exceptions in a [**`WimScript.ini`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) file)*
- All WinPE/WinRE  [WIMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) have `DISM` included within them.

  - **WinPE:** ***Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment*

    - *Such as a Windows Setup boot media (**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to access terminal)*
  - **WinRE:** ***Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment*

    - *WinRE is a WinPE image containing extra [WinPE Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference) vital to recovery*

---

#### Commands

*WinPE only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default, so `/ScratchDir` is required*

- **[Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image)** an image:

  ```powershell
  DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2019.11.03 @ 06:30" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
  ```

  **[Append](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image)** an Image:

  ```powershell
  DISM /Append-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2019.11.03 @ 06:30" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
  ```
- **[Apply](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image)** an image:

  ```powershell
  DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
  ```

  - If applying a system image, the following commands must be issued *prior to* booting:

    ```powershell
    bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /rebuildbcd
    ```

---

#### NOTE:

- **It's *impossible* for an ESD/WIM image to become corrupted**

  - Provided imaging commands are *always* issued with: `/CheckIntegrity` & `/Verify`
- **ESDs can only be taken of a *system* partition**

  - `/Compress:Recovery` is the only compression algorithm available.

    - ESD compression ratio is ~33% more efficient than the WIM compression ratio.
    - *In Windows 10, Microsoft only allows ESDs for Push-Button Reset exported images*
- **ESDs/WIMs are smart compression image formats**

  - Only changed files are added to an image when a new image is appended to it

    - Newly appended images utilize the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image from the previous image(s).

      - This allows for an image to remain small in relation to the data contained within.

---

#### DISM Prerequisites

- **Easy**

  1. Download & create a [bootable USB](https://rufus.ie/) via the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
  2. Once booted from it, press: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to open a terminal
  3. [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) commands

     - [Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image) or [Append](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image) an Image
     - [Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image)

       - Get [Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo) prior to applying, ensuring correct index [image] is being applied.
- **Custom:** *Create a WinPE/RE image*

  1. **Install:**

     - Windows ADK *(8 & 10)* is specific to the version of Windows installed.

       - For Windows >=10 v1809: [WinPE Addon for ADK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2087112)
       - For Windows <=10 v1803: [Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install)

         - **Select:** *Windows PE* & *Deployment Tools*
  2. **Create:**

     - [Microsoft WinPE Wiki](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive)

       - [Customize WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize)
       - [Customize WinRE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn898523.aspx)
     - [Reboot.Pro Wiki](http://reboot.pro/topic/19156-create-a-bootable-winpe-50-x64-usb-drive/)
  3. **Boot it**

---

### Example: `/Get-WIMinfo`

```powershell
PS $  ls -file

  Directory: Z:\WIM

    Mode                LastWriteTime            Length  Name
    ----                -------------            ------  ----
    -a----        2018.12.24 03:34:13   95,019,530,773B  Base.wim
    -a----        2016.06.14 22:32:36              568B  DISM.cmd
    -a----        2016.05.17 05:36:10               97B  wimscript.ini

PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

    Index : 1
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
      Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes

    Index : 2
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
      Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes

    Index : 3
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
      Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes

    Index : 4
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 1 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,588,267,910 bytes

    Index : 5
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 2 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,905,314,237 bytes

    Index : 6
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1809: Updated Applications
      Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes

  The operation completed successfully.
```

```powershell
PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:1

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 1
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
      Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 1
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 24288
      Files : 112665
      Created : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
      Modified : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:2

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 2
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
      Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 1
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 45803
      Files : 203058
      Created : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:47
      Modified : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:48
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:3

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 3
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
      Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 62409
      Files : 350446
      Created : 2018.06.01 - 19:09:51
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:4

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 4
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 1 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,588,267,910 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 61908
      Files : 346074
      Created : 2018.06.08 - 21:54:02
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:5

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 5
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 2 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,905,314,237 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 76113
      Files : 423408
      Created : 2018.06.09 - 20:38:36
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:6

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 6
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1809: Updated Applications
      Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17763
      ServicePack Build : 195
      ServicePack Level : 0
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 87659
      Files : 452028
      Created : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:13
      Modified : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:15
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

How to restore a windows 10 system image **from HDD to a NEW SSD** (error 0x80042415 & 0x80042412)

I have 2 SATA slots. I first tried to restore it using the SSD but by leaving the HDD inside. I had the errors "[...] change the disk signature using  DiskPart command UNIQUEID DISK ID. ( 0x80042415) "
Then I removed the HDD, I had this error "Re-image system disk fails error 0x80042412"

I found the solution on [sevenforums](https://www.sevenforums.com/backup-restore/65205-re-image-system-disk-fails-error-0x80042412.html) (thanks to Dale Mahalko):

> **The solution is to go to the command prompt and do some preformatting of the target drive/SSD using diskpart.**
>
> If you're unfamiliar with diskpart, it is best to unplug / eject your
> backup drive containing the recovery image, so you don't accidentally
> destroy it doing the following.
>
> Open the command prompt and type:
>
> ```
>  diskpart 
> list disk
> ```
>
> *(For me my new SSD is disk 0, but could be different for you.)*
>
> ```
> select disk 0 
> clean
> ```
>
> *(clean wipes out all existing drive partitioning.)*
>
> ```
> create partition primary size=100 align=4096
> ```
>
> *(aligning improves performance on SSD's and newer hard drives with 4096 byte sectors)*
>
> ```
> format quick fs=ntfs
> active 
> create partition primary align=4096
> format quick fs=ntfs 
> exit
> ```

It might be necessary before accessing the drive from windows disk management to switch the disk from "unallocated" following [these recommendation](https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/initialize-ssd-windows) . I did it before, butit's probably possible to do it directly using the command tool (on the restore panel) and diskpart.

1. open Disk Management by right clicking on Computer and selecting Manage, then Disk Management.
2. Select GUID partition table (GPT) and click OK. MBR (Master Boot Record) is best for certain legacy software compatibility, but GPT is better for modern systems and higher capacity storage devices.
3. Right-click in the area that says Unallocated and select New Simple Volume...
4. The New Simple Volume Wizard will open, click Next.
5. Leave the Specify Volume Size as the maximum (default value) and click Next.
6. Select a Drive Letter and click Next.
7. In the Format Partition screen, decide on a Volume label (the name you want to give the drive) and click Next.